# Como simplifico una condicion javascript

Tags: javascript

como simplifico la siguiente condicion:

```
x=3;
if (x==1 || x==2 || x==3){
    alert(x);
}
```

quiero simplicarlo, osea en ves de poner todo eso poner solo la x y las condiciones, casi como en python que se usa el "if x in [1,2,3]"

Comment: prueba así `x=3,1!=x&&2!=x&&3!=x||alert(x);`

Comment: podrias explicar que quiere decir simplificarlo? porque en todos los casos, escribis casi la misma cantidad de caracteres...

Answer (score 5):

Puedes usar algo asi

```js
x = 2
if ([1,2,3].includes(x)) {
  alert(x)
}
```

Comment: no me funciona :c

Comment: @UnHUmano algo habrás escrito mal...si ejecutas este snippet sí que funciona (o tampoco te funciona aquí?)

Comment: nose, te paso mi codigo? mi codigo es otro, toy usando sweetalert2

Comment: No, debes ponerlo en la pregunta si esta relacionado con ella, sino abre una nueva pregunta

Answer (score 3):

Otro método que se puede aplicar en este caso concreto sería con la función [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) de *Regex* de este modo:

```js
x=3;
if (/^[1-3]$/.test(x)) {
    alert(x);
}
```

donde le aplicamos una expresión regular a la función *test()*, que en este caso hace lo siguiente:

`/^[1-3]$/`

```
  /                 Inicia el delimitador
   ^                Especifica que la cadena esté al inicio
    [               Abre un conjunto de caracteres de posibles valores a encontrar
     1-3            Establece un rango entre el 1 y el 3
    ]               Cierra el conjunto de caracteres
   $                Establece que no debe haber nada más (fin de línea)
  /                 Cierre del delimitador
```